# Clustering with k-means for text classification based on similarity

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering, k-means

I have a column that contains all texts that I would like to cluster in order to find some patterns/similarity among each other.

```
Text
Word2vec is a two-layer neural net that processes text by “vectorizing” words. 

Its input is a text corpus and its output is a set of vectors: feature vectors that represent words in that corpus. 

While Word2vec is not a deep neural network, it turns text into a numerical form that deep neural networks can understand.

Documentation and examples for common text utilities to control alignment, wrapping, weight, and more.

NounEdit. text (countable and uncountable, plural texts). A writing consisting of multiple glyphs, characters, symbols or sentences.

Fish are gill-bearing aquatic craniate animals that lack limbs with digits.
```

I tried to determine the optimal number of clusters with elbow method, but unfortunately with no success. 
So I remove the stopwords and vectorised texts in the column:

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

def preprocessing(line):
    line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", line.lower())
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_lemmed = [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w) for w in words if w not in stop_words]
    return words_lemmed



  vect =TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=preprocessing)
    vect_text=vect.fit_transform(df['Text'])
    kmeans =KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(vect_text)

       n_clusters=3, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
```

Is it right to cluster the texts above based on their similarity using this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is how to cluster texts.

Firstly, an alternative approach to representing document meaning, you can use Doc2Vec and compare similarities between document embeddings (https://medium.com/wisio/a-gentle-introduction-to-doc2vec-db3e8c0cce5e).

Secondly, if you are unsure about the ideal number of clusters, instead of using k-means, you can use agglomerative clustering, which is essentially bottom-up method which clusters individual document embeddings by a distance metric to eventually merge all of the clusters to a "mega-cluster", containing all documents.

You can then see how the documents cluster together using a dendrogram.

Here is a good resource on agglomerative clustering : https://stackabuse.com/hierarchical-clustering-with-python-and-scikit-learn/